# Is the E-Gold's SRK a valuable security functionality?

Tags: security

I have noticed on the [E-Gold](https://www.e-gold.com/acct/login.html) page a small button called SRK which opens a popup containing a keypad working against keylogger. I am now wondering why this kind of module is not found anywhere else. Is there a reason NOT to use/implement this on our website?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such keyboard can be found on most modern sites, which deals with pin codes (for VISAs and so on), however it can have some problems (like problem with access from mobile devices).

Comment: Good point about the mobile device. Can you give me an example of a site using such keyboard ? Pin codes is something different imo.